# How to add a currency symbol in front of all the items in the listview which is saved in an sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-sqlite

I have an sqlite database which has values in it and I would like to put the pound symbol in front of all of the listview items. I do not want to put the pound symbol with the value because it is stored as an integer so it can be added somewhere else is the application. How do I do this?

For example I currently have:

- 10
- 20
- 30

and I want:

- £10
- £20
- £30

Here is my activity with my listview in it:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.afollestad.materialdialogs.DialogAction;
import com.afollestad.materialdialogs.MaterialDialog;

public class tab2income extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "tab2income";
    DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
    private ListView mListView;
    View rootView;
    Cursor incomedata;
    SimpleCursorAdapter sca;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2income, container, false);
        return rootView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewincome);
        mListView.setEmptyView(rootView.findViewById(R.id.empty));
        mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());


        populateListView();
    }

    private void populateListView() {
        Log.d(TAG, "populateListView: Displaying data in the ListView.");
        incomedata = mDatabaseHelper.getincomeData();
        sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, incomedata, new String[]{DatabaseHelper.INCOME_AMOUNT}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1}, 2);
        mListView.setAdapter(sca);

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                int csrpos = incomedata.getPosition();
                incomedata.moveToPosition(i);
                displayNoteDate(
                        incomedata.getString(incomedata.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.INCOME_NOTES)),
                        incomedata.getString(incomedata.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.INCOME_DATE)),
                        l);
                incomedata.moveToPosition(csrpos);
            }
        });
    }




    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        incomedata.close();
    }

    public void displayNoteDate(String noteContent, String dateValue, final long noteID) {
        MaterialDialog.Builder builder= new MaterialDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .title("Income Information")
                .content("Note: "+noteContent+"\nDate: "+ dateValue)
                .positiveText("edit")
                .negativeText("delete")
                .neutralText("close")
                .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"EDIT",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .onNeutral(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                    }
                })
                .onNegative(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                        mDatabaseHelper.deleteincomeData(Long.toString(noteID));
                        incomedata = mDatabaseHelper.getincomeData();
                        sca.swapCursor(incomedata);
                    }
                });
        builder.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not just adding a compound drawable to your custom TextView item?

Answer (score 2):

You have to follow this way.. It will help you..

Put it in your strings.xml

```
<string name="currency_symbol">\u00a3</string>
```

Then add this string us prefix on your value..
For Example

```
public String[] getValuesList(Cursor c) {
       String[] valuesList = new String[c.getCount()];
        int i=0;
        if (c.getCount() > 0) {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    //Here let us assume 2  is Your INCOME_AMOUNT column index
                    String value = R.string.currency_symbol+c.getString(2);
                    valuesList[i] = value;
                    i++;
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
            c.close();
        }
        return valuesList;
    }
```

you have to replace you populateListView() method
like

```
private void populateListView() {
        Log.d(TAG, "populateListView: Displaying data in the ListView.");
        incomedata = mDatabaseHelper.getincomeData();
        String amountListValues[] = getValuesList(incomedata);
        sca = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,  amountListValues);
        mListView.setAdapter(sca);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {               
                incomedata.moveToPosition(i);
                displayNoteDate(
                        incomedata.getString(incomedata.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.INCOME_NOTES)),
                        incomedata.getString(incomedata.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.INCOME_DATE)),
                        l);
                incomedata.moveToPosition(i);
            }
        });
    }
```

It will Show With pound sign...

If you need other math signs/unicode characters refer this link http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_common_symbols.html

Comment: How would I apply this to data coming from an SQLite database?

Comment: How would I add this to my code above? What should I do with it? Sorry, I am new to android app development so I am still learning.

Comment: This does not work I get the error 'attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery: select * from income_table' and the code will not run anyway without taking away the swapCursor as seen in my code

Comment: Your cursor object is closed so its happening, please check it

Comment: This does not work at all I cannot even add new values into the sqlite database

Answer (score 0):

You could change method `getincomeData` so that the query uses something along the lines of :-

```
SELECT '$' || incomedata AS incomedata FROM incometable;
```

Where **incomedata** is a column within the table BUT the **incomedata** column in the resultant cursor is the respective value prefixed with **$**.

Here's a real example (shows both the before and after values):-

[image]

This is based upon the column **productusageccost**. The SQL used was:-

`SELECT productusagecost AS originaldata, '$' || productusagecost AS productusagecost  FROM productusage`

This takes the **productusagecost** column, outputs it as column **originaldata** and also as **productusagecost** but where the **productusagecost** column that is prefixed with **$**. You wouldn't actually need `productusagecost AS originaldata,` as this was just used for illustration.

You would then do this for each column that you wanted to be prefixed with the symbol. Noting that if you use the data for calculations then you'd have to remove the prefix or use a second column (*hence a reason why the example includes the originaldata column*).

---

You could instead use a CustomAdapter to prefix the value when setting the respective view. e.g. in the `bindView` method (`getView` could also be used) of a CustomAdpater, I have:-

`productcost.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(csr.getDouble(productusage_cost_offest)));`

This uses the device's currency formatting. *(You should probably research the pro's and cons of using **`getCurrentcyInstance`** if using this.)*

Comment: `    public Cursor incomeDatasymbol() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT '$' || INCOME_AMOUNT AS INCOME_AMOUNT FROM income_table", null);
        return res;
    }` Is that how I am supposed to use it?

Comment: That looks correct. `public Cursor incomeDatasymbol() { SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); return db.rawQuery("SELECT '$' || INCOME_AMOUNT AS INCOME_AMOUNT FROM income_table", null);}` would also work and is a little shorter.

Comment: Ok, I will try this because the one I posted does not work as it gives me _id not found error even though I have that column